# DHCP Server No Subnet Declaration

Tags: networking, dhcp

For the past 2 hours I tried to solve the No Subnet declaratio for enp0s8 (192.168.1.1)

My **/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf** looks like this

```
authoritative;
default-lease-time 86400; 
max-lease-time 86400000; 

option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option router 192.168.1.1;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
option domain-name "xxx.xxx.xx" 

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.11 192.168.0.254;
}

host vmpsateam01-01{
  hardware ethernet 08:00:27:82:cd:38
  fixed-address 192.168.0.1;
}
```

The is set to listen on enp0s8 in **/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

```
INTERFACESv4="enp0s8"
```

The static IP address of the network interface is in the subnet:

```
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe82:cd38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:82:cd:38
```

Also in **etc/network/interfaces** I configured the router to have a static IP

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.1
  gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Still, when restarting ics-dhcp-server I receive a **No subnet declaration for enp0s8 (192.168.1.1)** although 192.168.1.1/24 is in the subnet defined in dhcpd.conf.
Thanks for any advice!

(I know there are many question like this, but none of them helped so far)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necrobumping, but I experienced the same for my `isc-dhcp-server` setup.

I changed the pool start- and end addresses and after restarting the `isc-dhcp-service`, the same subnet error as OP described appeared after the `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server` cmd.

My conclusion is that restarting the `isc-dhcp-server.service` after implementing changes in its configuration, will not advertise the changes to other network components entirely.
So restarting the (virtual) machine should be preferred to apply the changes effectively.